# SQL query with a concatenated AND statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the opposite of a condition:

```
SELECT TAX.* 
FROM TAX
JOIN STATUS ON TAX.TAX_ID = STATUS.TAX_ID
WHERE STATUS.VALUE = 'ACTIVE'
   OR (STATUS.VALUE = 'COLLECTED' AND STATUS.COLLECTEDDATE >= '20000101')
```

What I want is the records that do NOT conform to the where clause.

I've tried

```
SELECT TAX.* 
FROM TAX
JOIN STATUS on TAX.TAX_ID = STATUS.TAX_ID
WHERE STATUS.VALUE != 'ACTIVE'
  AND (STATUS.VALUE != 'COLLECTED' and STATUS.COLLECTEDDATE < '20000101')
```

but it looks like I'm missing records. I think SQL Server drops records and I suspect that it drops the parentheses.

Can I get a recommendation on how this should go?

Thanks

Comment: change the `AND` back to `OR`. So... `WHERE STATUS.VALUE != 'ACTIVE'
OR (STATUS.VALUE != 'COLLECTED' and STATUS.COLLECTEDDATE < '20000101')`

Comment: If you want to exactly invert the clause, why not wrap it in `NOT (...)` rather than laboriously inverting all the operators yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways

1. add a NOT at the very beginning like below,

so your query becomes

```
Select TAX.* from TAX
JOIN STATUS on TAX.TAX_ID = STATUS.TAX_ID
WHERE NOT
(STATUS.VALUE = 'ACTIVE'
OR (STATUS.VALUE = 'COLLECTED' and STATUS.COLLECTEDDATE >= '20000101'))
```

2. another way is to use logical operation negation which says !(a+b)= !a.!b and !(a.b)= !a+!b

so your query becomes

```
Select TAX.* from TAX
JOIN STATUS on TAX.TAX_ID = STATUS.TAX_ID
WHERE STATUS.VALUE != 'ACTIVE'
AND (STATUS.VALUE != 'COLLECTED' or STATUS.COLLECTEDDATE < '20000101')
```

Comment: either one of those preferred for speed?

Comment: @arcee123 the second one as the NOT() will work on results of ()

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: I sincerely doubt that's correct, and when in doubt, the answer is usually "try it and see". The optimizer is free to rewrite either query, neither can make effective use of indexes due to the negated conditions, and consequently I'd be surprised if there's actually a difference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree! It depends on indexes and what unfolds in the plan